# How to prevent line breaks with jasper-reports HTML export when using textfield truncation?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Using iReport 4.5.0, I'm setting these two properties and values:

- `net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char=true`
- `net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.suffix=...`

The intent is to add "..." to the end of textfields whenever they must be truncated, and that the truncation determination happens at the character level, rather than at the word level.  This works as expected when exporting to PDF.  However, when exporting to HTML, the last truncated token (with the suffix appended) will often, though not always, wrap incorrectly.  (It does this even though StretchType is set to No Stretch.) Example:

[image: Jasper HTML Export Error]

If I change `net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char=false` (so that it breaks on words instead of characters) it seems to work more often, but only because word breaks usually leave more space for the suffix.  The unexpected line wrapping still occurs with word breaks, especially if I increase the length of the given suffix.

My best guess is that the HTML exporter measurement isn't precisely calculating the width required by the given suffix (if it's calculating it at all).

1. **Can anyone confirm?**
2. **Any suggestions as to a workaround?**

It seems like with StretchType set to No Stretch, that the HTML exporter should probably also set white-space:nowrap. However, although that would prevent the line from wrapping,  the end of the suffix would be partially hidden (due to overflow:hidden styling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"My best guess is that the HTML exporter measurement isn't precisely calculating the width required by the given suffix (if it's calculating it at all)."

1. I confirm that this is surely the reason.

But there's not really a simple workaround. Your PDF is good, so you're doing something right. Well... you're doing lots of things right. ;-)

In HTML you don't know--in a very fundamental way--the precise details of the font that will render the text. You can certainly specify the font. But the client machine might not have it. Or it might have one that is the same... but not quite the same. Or the client might choose to use a different font or different size via various client-side override mechanisms.

If you try different fonts, you should notice slightly different results. You may be able to find one that works better more often. (Clearly, this isn't 100% perfect.)

If you aren't using Font Extensions, then you should. If you are using Font Extensions, then you can specify the list of fonts in descending preference that ought to be used in the HTML. This should give you enough control to get behavior that is good in a large number of cases. Often you can make it perfect in all of the cases that you care about.